# toliet backing up after roter rooter and replaced toliet

Tags: toilet

Toilet started backing up. Called roter rooter. Unclogged but they suggested it was the toilet (old)  Replaced with new toilet however after my husband used toilet it backed up and wouldn't flush

Comment: get a new husband ... lol ... just kidding .... was the toilet tested after installation?

Comment: Try a different sewer cleaning company. I've had similar issues and ended up talking with a local guy who cleaned out the sewer with a larger "bit" and considerably longer snake than the "big company" guys use and it took care of the problem. The "big company" guys weren't getting at it with the right tools.

Comment: It's one of the above. My money's on them not having got it all the way into the street, not checking it with a camera, or not using a bit that will cut roots. That's assuming you don't have a septic system...

Comment: Who replaces a toilet to fix a plug? Only conn artists!

Comment: I'd like to know if you are on a public sewer system, or a private septic system.

Comment: The question is "How did they clean the drain" then did they go all the way to the street. In the "How" if they used a clean out it could be the section between the clean out and the toilet or and yes I've seen it a blocked vent that goes up to the roof as the toilet has to vent or it will backup and burp in your face. Squirrels like vents..

Answer (score 1):

Left as an answer because with the information provided I believe you were taken advantage of ( screwed in common terms)
Wow, I would call the bbb and state exactly what you did here. Sounds like a really scum type of business!!!!!!!! Sorry but old toilets have more water and actually clear the piping better,  to tell the truth you should have a case and find a different plumber and get some of your $ back !!!!!!!!

Comment: So true about the old toilets.  I know many people who have regretted replacing their old ones.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would contact the installer, and have them come back right away, but be incredibly friendly and nice and positive when you contact them.